# Typo3 Fluid - Checking if a radio-button is selected or not

Tags: forms, typo3, conditional-statements, fluid, typo3-9.x

I am currently working on a solution for a decision tree for a contact form, where you will be asked what your problem is and depending on the selection the content changes.

My current code looks like this. I have starting-form including some radiobuttons.

For each selection posibility, i created it's own partial.

My thoughts are now, that if you select radio button 1, partial 1 should be rendered.

How can i check within a fluid/vhs condition, wheather a specific radiobutton/checkbox is selected or not.

Or maybe you have some suggestions for doing it a different way?

I'm working with Typo3 9.5.

Thank you very much in advance!

Luca

```
<f:form.radio name="Radio1" value="value1" />
<f:form.radio name="Radio2" value="value2" />

<f:if condition="Radio1 is selected">
   <f:render partial="Layer1/Parial1" />
</f:if>

<f:if condition="Radio2 is selected">
   <f:render partial="Layer1/Parial2" />
</f:if>
```

Comment: You propably don't want the behaviour when the form is built but when the user changes the selection in the radio button, right? I propose to do this part with JavaScript.